# Conversion of complex number/quaternion to real vector

Tags: complex-numbers, notation, vectors, quaternions

Is there a notation/function for "converting" (for want of a better word) a complex number or quaternion into a real vector with a dimension of 2 or 4?

E.g. $2 + 3i + 4j + 9k$ would be $(2, 3, 4, 9)$, $2 + 3j$ would be $(2, 0, 3, 0)$, $2 + 3i$ would be $(2, 3)$.

Comment: I think you just have to mention you're identifying $\Bbb C$ with $\Bbb R^2$, or $\Bbb H$ with $\Bbb R^4$, in the obvious one.

Comment: @J.G. Is there a formal way of representing this?

Comment: I've just realised my comment has a typo: "one" should be "way". No, I don't think there's a formal way to put it, at least not if you mean within an equation environment. Written mathematics still relies heavily on the words between symbols.